# open shared calender with access (vba)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I wrote a script that should open a calender (`Wartung`) in outlook and add the meeting. But i get an **"object not found error"** in my script.

I also tried `Set outtest = outApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)`, that works but only for my personal calender. "`Wartung`" is a shared calender.

```
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outtest As Object
Dim ZeitEnd As Date
Set OutApp = GetOutlook
Set outtest = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("Meine Kalender").Items("Wartung").CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

ZeitEnd = DateAdd("h", 4, lstZeit)

    With outtest

        .Subject = "SAP Patche: " & lstSID
        .Start = lstDat + lstZeit
        .End = lstDat + ZeitEnd
        .Body = "TEST"

        'Params not in use
            '.AllDayEvent = True
            '.MeetingStatus = olMeeting

        .Display

    End With

Set OutApp = Nothing
Set outtest = Nothing
```

For a better view:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you had broken up

```
Set outtest = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("Meine Kalender").Items("Wartung").CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
```

the highlight indicating the line with the error would be more focused.

Wartung is a folder.

You can Add items to non default folders.

The code could look something like this.

```
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim outCal as Folder
Dim outCalitems as items
Dim outtest as Object

Set OutApp = GetOutlook
Set OutNs = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set outCal = OutNs.Folders("Meine Kalender")
Set outCal = outCal.Folders("Wartung")

Set outCalitems = outCal.Items

Set outtest = outCalitems.Add(olAppointmentItem)
```